# Converting DXF to ESRI Shapefile using ogr2ogr

Tags: shapefile, ogr2ogr, dxf, ogrinfo

I like to convert [this DXF file](https://gist.github.com/johnjohndoe/576f99df6f442cdb1eb8e324d602b1a7) to ESRI Shapefiles. I tried the following command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" test.shp Umweltzone-Neu-Ulm.dxf
```

... which output the following warnings and errors:

> Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'ExtendedEntity' to 'ExtendedEn'
>   Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'EntityHandle' to 'EntityHand'
>   ERROR 1: Attempt to write non-polygon (LINESTRING) geometry to POLYGON type shapefile.
>   ERROR 1: Unable to write feature 1 from layer entities.
>   ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
>   translation of layer entities (use -skipfailures to skip errors)

Inspecting the file with ogrinfo does not give a helpful advice for me:

```
ogrinfo -so -al Umweltzone-Neu-Ulm.dxf 
INFO: Open of `Umweltzone-Neu-Ulm.dxf'
      using driver `DXF' successful.

Layer name: entities
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 3
Extent: (573038.389500, 5359699.934800) - (576023.432710, 5361356.286500)
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
Layer: String (0.0)
SubClasses: String (0.0)
ExtendedEntity: String (0.0)
Linetype: String (0.0)
EntityHandle: String (0.0)
Text: String (0.0)
```

Also, from the `Extent` I am guessing that the EPSG code is different to `4326`. But which?

What is the correct command to perform the conversion?

## Related

- [ogr2ogr coverting DXF to shapefile, why am I losing part of the feature?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66417/ogr2ogr-coverting-dxf-to-shapefile-why-am-i-losing-part-of-the-feature)
- [Specifying element type for DXF creation using ogr2ogr](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80293/specifying-element-type-for-dxf-creation-using-ogr2ogr)

Comment: You have mixed geometries that can't be saved to a single shapefile

Comment: @IanTurton Is there anything I can do about this? Can I extract one geometry and then the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guessed the SRS to EPSG:25832 (UTM 32N) by looking at the DXF file with QGIS.

With ogr2ogr:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON umweltzone.geojson Umweltzone-Neu-Ulm.dxf -limit 1 -s_srs EPSG:25832 -t_srs EPSG:4326
```

- -f GeoJSON              output format
- umweltzone.geojson      output file name
- Umweltzone-Neu-Ulm.dxf  input file name
- -limit 1                output only one feature per layer
- -s_srs EPSG:25832       source srs
- -t_srs EPSG:4326        target srs

you can create a geojson file. Looking at the source file, it shows there are three features: a point, a linestring and a polygon.
Limiting the feature (and knowing the polygon is the first one) gives you the polygon. 
You can omit the limit parameter and you'll get all three features.

edit: with `-f 'ESRI Shapefile'` instead of GeoJson you will get a shapefile

edit: to create a Shapefile for each feature type you have to run ogr2ogr for each type

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" umweltzone_point.shp Umweltzone-Neu-Ulm.dxf -nlt Point  -s_srs EPSG:25832 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -skipfailures
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" umweltzone_line.shp Umweltzone-Neu-Ulm.dxf -nlt LINESTRING  -s_srs EPSG:25832 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -skipfailures
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" umweltzone_polygon.shp Umweltzone-Neu-Ulm.dxf -nlt POLYGON  -s_srs EPSG:25832 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -skipfailures
```

You have to use the `-skipfailures` parameter, because it is not possible to write different geometry types to one shapefile.

Comment: It's a stab at an answer, but it doesn't really address the issue.  What if you want three shapefiles, one for each feature type (point, line, polygon)

Comment: you could also filter the geomtype for each shapefile, so you do not get so much error messages:
-where "ogr_geometry = 'LINESTRING'