# Convert DXF files into shapefiles using ogr2ogr

Tags: shapefile, ogr2ogr, dxf, cmd

I'm trying to convert DXF to shapefile through org2org in GDAL
Ask about some questions and errors during the attempt.

Here's the command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" test_13.shp Ceco.NET-Architecture-Tm-53.dxf -skipfailures
```

ERROR 1: Attempt to write non-linestring (POINT) geometry to ARC type shapefile.

Comment: One shapefile can contain only points, lines, or polygons. Now it seems that the first features in the DXF drawing have been linestrings. When ogr2ogr tries to write the first point from the DXF file it fails.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
So, should I express the first part of the file as a point that is not a linestrings?

Comment: The commands DXF to Shape are here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/348873/276

Comment: Without knowing what you have in your DXF drawing it is hard to tell exactly what to do, but because you have a mixture of at least points and lines in your DXF layer they do not fit on one shapefile. Maybe I would convert data first info GeoPackage with `-f GPKG` and allowing all kind of geometries with `-nlt geometry`. Then you can open the gpkg file with QGIS and see what you have, and perhaps split the layer by geometry type if your final goal is to have shapefiles.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a try